# system null reference exception

Tags: c#

Am getting

System null reference exception:object reference not set to an instsnce of the object

```
Line 59:             **XmlText nameText = xmldoc.CreateTextNode(name.Text);**
Line 60:             XmlText locationText = xmldoc.CreateTextNode(location.Text);
Line 61:             XmlText emailText = xmldoc.CreateTextNode(email.Text)
```

Plz help me out frm this..

Answer (score 7):

Well, there are two obvious potential causes:

Either `name` is null, or `xmldoc` is null. We can't tell which of those is true, but you should be able to.

A `NullReferenceException` is what happens when you try to *dereference* a reference value which turns out to be null. For example:

```
string x = null;
int length = x.Length; // Bang - NullReferenceException
```

Jakub wrote: "Just attach a debugger and check the values of `name` and `xmldoc`."

Personally I'd write a unit test and *think* about the code instead of leaping in with a debugger. Using a debugger will find the *immediate* problem, but thinking about the code will lead you to work out *why* you've got to this situation, and allow you to treat the symptom rather than the cause. Of course, you can think as well as using a debugger, but I've often seen developers use an interactive debugger as a crutch to *avoid* thinking.